# Facing some problem to get required data from mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two Mysql tables.One is matches and other one is betsettings. i have match_id as a foreign key in betsettings table.Now how can i get betsettings information for every match_name ? i want to show every matches all betsettings information under that match name.I am using laravel

matches table:

```
    Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('match_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

betsettings table:

```
    Schema::create('betsettings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('match_id')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('close_time');
        $table->string('status')->default('active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('betsettings', function( $table) {
          $table->foreign('match_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('matches')
          ->onDelete('cascade')
          ->onUpdate('cascade');
         });
```

Comment: is this PHP? Is this a specific framework and/or ORM on top of PHP? Please mention it, then we know what we're dealing with. P.S. In pure SQL you'd use an INNER JOIN to accomplish this.

Comment: i am using a php based frame work named laravel.i already mention that.

Comment: Sorry I missed it right at the end of your block of text. You should add suitable tags, too then it's more obvious. I will add them for you, on this occasion. If you tag your question accurately, then there is more chance that people with the relevant skills will see it.

Comment: Anyway, what have you tried so far? What have you researched? I see no attempt to even write a query. If you tried something, please show it then we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at eloquent relationships to better understanding how laravel handle with the relationships

I assume you have models for each table, lets define a relationship between those table using models.

in Match Model

```
public function betsettings(){
    return $this->hasOne(BetSetting:class);
}
```

in BetSetting Model

```
public function match(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Match:class);
}
```

Now you can get bet settings for each match using eager loading. Here is an example

```
$match = Match::with("betsettings")->find($id);

$match->betsettings // gives you related bet settings
```